# adding numbers to a list from a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Simple code bit:

```
import re

data = "t3st 11.22.3333.44 bl4h"
r=re.compile(r'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
s=r.search(data)
print (s.group())
```

At this point s.group() = "11.22.3333.44" which is great.
I'd like to make a list from the number groups within the decimal points:

```
list = ["11","22","3333","44"]
```

How can I make this work?  Thanks.

Comment: May be there is a better way in the first place, but `x.split('.')` works, where `x` is your current output.

Comment: `([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)`  captures the 4 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply split your output string on `.`?

```
>>> import re

>>> data = "t3st 11.22.3333.44 bl4h"
>>> r=re.compile(r'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
>>> s=r.search(data)
>>> print (s.group().split('.'))
['11', '22', '3333', '44']
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern to one group per number:

```
import re

data = "t3st 11.22.3333.44 bl4h"
r=re.compile(r'([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)') # individual groups per numbers
s=r.search(data)
print ( list( s.groups()) )
```

Output:

```
['11', '22', '3333', '44']
```

`Match.groups()` returns a tuple, see [Doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups)